# Selenium WebDriver cannot click on element (works only on 1 of 2 pcs)

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Chrome and Selenium with Java to do some automation testing.
What could be the issue for getting the `element cannot be clicked at x, y` on 1 machine, but working perfectly on another?

The pcs have the same selenium library version, same Chrome browser version and the same chromedriver.exe version.

Both of the chrome instances start off with no extensions on both pcs.

**LATER EDIT:**

I've determined that the issue is only persistent on some Acer machines with integrated video cards. The issue appears only on 1 page where there is an animated slideshow, all other elements work on all machines. Also tested on another machine with dedicated gfx and it worked fine. Is it absurd to think that the animation can cause this?

Comment: Is the browser zoom level 100% ?

Comment: Yes. Everytime a run starts the browser defaults to 100% zoom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying on a few more machines, I can **safely assume** that the issue was with the integrated Intel HD card on the machine.

It seems that selenium + javascript slideshow + intel HD